Loading images paths from DB, React, Bootstrap, ASP.NET, Microsoft SQL Server
i have this problem and solution is nowhere to be found. Images aren't showing in web page.
I know first imports
import pizzaIcon3 from "../images/pol-pol-pizz.jpg";
are doing nothing, but it is leftover from hardcoded site. Also it tried to use it with backend and DB, but nothing works.
So this is the code
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Card, Button, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import axios from "axios";
import pizzaIcon1 from "../images/mar-pizz.jpg";
import pizzaIcon2 from "../images/pep-szyn-kiel-pizz.jpg";
import pizzaIcon3 from "../images/pol-pol-pizz.jpg";
import burIcon1 from "../images/mar-pizz.jpg";
import burIcon2 from "../images/pep-szyn-kiel-pizz.jpg";
import burIcon3 from "../images/pol-pol-pizz.jpg";

const ProductCard = ({product}) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProducts = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('https://localhost:7029/api/Product');
                setProducts(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching products: ', error);
            }
        };
        fetchProducts();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Container className="mt-5">
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <Row>
                {products.map(product => (
                    <Col key={product.id} className="col-md-4">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img src={product.imagePath} alt="Pizza"  />
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>{product.ingredients}</Card.Text>
                                <Button variant="primary">Add to Cart</Button>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}
export default ProductCard;

this is console log on front
0: {id: 1, type: 'Pizza', name: 'Pizza 1', ingredients: 'ciasto, sos pomidorowy, ser, szynka, pieczarki, oregano', price: 47.99, …} 
2: {id: 3, type: 'Pizza', name: 'Pizza 3', ingredients: 'ciasto, sos pomidorowy, ser, szynka, pieczarki, oregano', price: 45.99, …} 
3: {id: 4, type: 'Burger', name: 'Burger 1', ingredients: 'bułka, wołowina, sałata, pomidor, cebula, sos', price: 12.99, …} 
4: {id: 5, type: 'Burger', name: 'Burger 2', ingredients: 'bułka, kurczak, sałata, ogórek, majonez, ketchup', price: 10.99, …} 
5: {id: 6, type: 'Burger', name: 'Burger 3', ingredients: 'bułka, wołowina, ser, bekon, ogórek kiszony, sos BBQ', price: 14.99, …} 

id: 2
imagePath: "../images/pep-szyn-kiel-pizz.jpg"
ingredients: "ciasto, sos pomidorowy, ser, szynka, pieczarki, oregano"
name: "Pizza 2"
price: 35.99
 type: "Pizza"

enter image description here
this is structure from DB, i tried to put image path into quote sign, " " <- this :P and then error occured me. With that setting site loads and shows alternative text for image. Please help me :D
I expect images to show on my website

import imports a file at build time, not run time. So ../images/... isn't a path to an image after your project builds. Do you have a public/ folder? Try putting images in there. Else, we will need more information about how your app builds to be able to help.

i do not use import now, now i store image path in database, and then map the this information to src attribute.

and i have this images in images folder in my project

../images/pep-szyn-kiel-pizz.jpg is a local path (i.e. in your build/ folder. You're saying you have a separate database? Then you need the absolute path to your database.

ok i fixed it i put only images names to DB and then create a path like that:
<Card.Img variant="top" src={require('../images/'+product.imagePath+'.jpg')} alt="Pizza"  />
